# Strange date behaviour in bash

Tags: linux, date

I am trying to add hours to a given datetime in bash and its giving weird results

This is just to check if its parsing the date time correctly

`$ date -d "2020-01-21 12:00:00"`

**Tue 21 Jan 12:00:00 UTC 2020**

Now when I try to do date math

`$ date -d "2020-01-21 12:00:00 +2 hour"`

**Tue 21 Jan 11:00:00 UTC 2020**

I tried few other operations but similar behaviour.

If I change my format then it behaves correctly for eg.

`date -d "12:00:00 2020-01-21  +2 hour"`

**Tue 21 Jan 14:00:00 UTC 2020**

not sure whats going on here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash`; `date` is an external program.

Comment: Just glue `2` with `hour`. `date -d "12:00:00 2020-01-21 +2hour"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+2` is being interpreted as an explicit timezone specifier (equivalent to EET), so `date -d "2020-01-21 12:00:00 +2 hour"` is interpreted the same as `date -d "2020-01-21 12:00:00 EET hour"`, which adds *one* hour to the timezone-adjusted time specified.

You can either provide an explicit timezone (as suggested by Maaz) so that `+2 hour` is syntactically an additional offset, or you can move it to the *beginning* of the expression, where it can't be parsed as a timezone.

```
date -d "+ 2 hour 2020-01-21 12:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to pass the timezone in command as well like UTC/CT/IST, so that date command can understand the point of reference to add extra hours.

For example if you are in UTC timezone, then following will produce correct output for you.

```
date -d "2020-01-21 12:00:00 UTC + 2 hour"
```

Comment: More specifically, `+2` itself is a valid timezone specifier, equivalent to EET, so the original is parsed as adding *one* hour to 12:00:00 EET. Adding UTC (or any timezone) explicitly makes `+2 hour` an additional offset as expected.